# how to save hex string to binary file?

Tags: delphi

I have a hexString and how can I convert that string into binary and save as a binary file with custom extension? the following is a sample code block which I used to save the string into file.

```
function HexToString(H: String): String;
var I: Integer;
begin
  Result:= '';
  for I := 1 to length (H) div 2 do
    Result:= Result+Char(StrToInt('$'+Copy(H,(I-1)*2+1,2)));
end;

procedure saveAs();
p, k, c, tmp: HexStr;
begin

   k := StringToHex('mykey');

   //TO DO 
   //I need to convert 'k' into binary and save as new file
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Delphi's RTL has [`HexToBin()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.HexToBin) functions. You can use [`FileCreate()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FileCreate) + [`FileWrite()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FileWrite), or [`TFileStream`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TFileStream), to write the binary data to file using any filename + extension you want.

Comment: sir, I need code samples to implement that can you help me?